# How to declare a variable in a Slurm batch file and use it in the multiprog conf?

Tags: slurm

In my current project I have the problem of overlong commands in the slurm multiprog conf (it has a limit of 256 chars).

To circumvent this, I'd like to define variables (paths, userdata, filenames) in the batchfile and use them in the multiprog config file.

Aunt google and the rather spartan documentation didn't give me hints. I looked into using environment variables, but haven't found a way to set my own.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command line in the multiprog configuration file is `exec`'ed rather than parsed with Bash so you need to invoke the Bash shell explicitly.

For instance:

```
$ export VAR=VALUE
```

I set a `VAR` var in the environment with value `VALUE` and use the following conf file to illustrate:

```
$ cat multi.conf
0   echo $VAR
1   bash -c 'echo $VAR'
```

Task 0 will simply be `exec`'ed while task 1 will first be parsed by Bash. The result:

```
$ srun -n2 -l --multi-prog multi.conf
0: $VAR
1: VALUE
```

Taks 0 echoes the variable name while task 1 echoes the variable's value. But beware that you need to spend 10 additional chars.